# Installing pip packages on a server where I have only ftp access?

Tags: python, ftp, pip

We (our company) have a webserver which is fully hosted, I can only access it through FTP and put files on it that way.  It has a couple of Python scripts installed in a `/cgi-bin/` folder, and I've been asked to upgrade the functionality of one of them (it uses Apache and regular old CGI, if that helps). Unfortunately, to do this I need to use a package from pip, one with several dependencies.

Is there any way to install packages from pip to a server I only have FTP access to? Can I maybe just copy all the folders containing the pip package and its dependencies to some location on the server? I imagine putting it in `/cgi-bin/` would be unsafe, but I do have access to non-`public_html` folders. How would I have to configure my python scripts to be able to import these, if it is even possible to do it this way?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There is a way, that is to contact your host's technical support.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, it is not possible to install packages through an FTP server. Pip works fine using an HTTP server or by downloading it locally. To use it with an HTTP server, just do `pip install <package-name> -i <url-of-pip-packages>`.